# Вывод подключённых файлов без пути

Tags: php

Можно ли вывести список подключённых файлов без пути их нахождения, просто имя и расширение?

```
$files = get_included_files();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно

```
$files = get_included_files();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo basename($file, __FILE__) . '<br>';
}
```